# Graph API POST Request (Create List Item) 'accessDenied' error for Guest AD Users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have quite a strange issue (well I think it is)... I'm building a web application using Ionic Angular and this application needs to submit information to a SharePoint site within our company. Authentication for the application is handled using [Microsoft Authentication Library for Angular (v1)](http://Microsoft%20Authentication%20Library%20for%20Angular) and the users of the application can either be AzureAD Guest users, or actual company users. The application successfully authenticates both types of users and they are issued an *IDtoken*, along with an *accessToken*. The access token is then used to perform GET, PATCH and POST Graph API requests against particular lists within a SharePoint site.

If I'm logged in as a full user... there is no issue, the app can successfully perform all three request types against the lists. However, if I'm logged into the application as a Guest user, I can only successfully perform GET and PATCH requests, but not POST:

[A Postman POST request using the access token retrieved via MSAL authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RODtu.png)

I have checked the scopes within the token using https://jwt.ms and confirm that the following scopes are present:

- Sites.Manage.All
- Sites.Read.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read profile openid email

The permissions for the lists are granted through membership of an Azure AD Domain/Security group and both; the full user and guest user are members.

To further add to this, I've logged into the SharePoint site online as the Guest User and I can successfully See, Add and Edit List items from the list, but I can't seem to do this via the Graph API.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, or has any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

This is my app registration setup regarding permissions:
[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m618.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permissions in Azure Portal. When getting the access token with a signed-in user, you need to make sure the **delegated** permission `Sites.ReadWrite.All` has been set, and **grant admin consent** for your tenant.

[image]

And the scope should be added this permission for requesting an access token.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id=<client_id>
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FSites.ReadWrite.All
&code=<authorization_code, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code>
&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret=<client_secret>
```

It may be a delay about 5-10 mins after adding the permission.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this is already the case, I can't seem to provide an image on this comment, so will update the question with it.  The app registration has the following delegate permissions, each of which are granted for the organisation by another Azure Admin: Sites.Manage.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, User.All

Comment: Also, when triggering the authentication flow via MSAL this is the URL: 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?response_type=id_token
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20sites.readwrite.all%20sites.manage.all
&client_id=<client_id>
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Floading
&state=<state>
&nonce=<nonce>
&client_info=<client_info>
&client-request-id=<lient-request-id>
&response_mode=fragment`

Comment: As the url shows, you use [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).  `response_type=id_token` means getting the id_token but not access token, try with `response_type=token`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, however the MSAL library that I'm using is retrieving accessTokens with the defined scopes automatically for me, I don't call these authorisation/token URLs manually. When I inspect the payload of a successfull login/auth. I can see both an _idToken_ and _accessToken_ retrieved. And when I inspect the accessToken via jwt.ms I can see the defined scopes. So I would expect the token to be valid and useable, (and it actually is for GET and PATCH) for the Graph resource...